# Should Cocoa Models contain their own data access methods?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I am relatively new to developing Cocoa applications on the Mac and come from a .NET C# background. I was wondering if a Cocoa Model object should contain its own data access methods such as Create, Update and Delete etc. Apples documentation seems to lean towards the Model doing everything but it doesn't seem right to have a Model (ie UserModel) which has a method named GetUsers which returns a collection of UserModels!

In ASP.NET MVC all my Models are just a representation of a Business object (ie a User) or a View. Using the example from above it would be the controllers responsibility to call a service (Business Layer or something of that nature) and get back a list of UserModel objects. The same controller would also populate a UserModel with data and pass that as a parameter to some other service which could then perform an Update or a Delete.

Any thoughts on this subject would be greatly appreciated as example code from Apple tend to be rather simple and don't really touch on CRUD type operations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also come from a .NET background and I agree that Apple sometimes confuse things a bit. I tend to keep my domain models clean and implement a data access service. The only time I do it differently is if I am using CoreData in which my domain level objects are also CoreData objects (so they have underlying data persistence) HOWEVER I still use a Storage Service / Data Access Service to retrieve and save through.

If you want an example of a Storage Service / DAL I use then one of my blog posts contains it....[CoreData Example](http://www.locassa.com/index.php/2011/05/temporary-storage-in-apples-coredata/)

Comment: Excellent Simon thanks for the answer, exactly what I am looking for. Just out of interest would it be possible to show me how you have organised your Mac projects (simple screenshot) in Xcode to integrate a Data Access Service. I would normally have these as separate projects in Visual Studio and create references. I have tried to do this with folder in Xcode but not sure its the right way to go. Thanks again for all your help and its good to speak to a fellow .NET developer who has gone through the process of learning how to do things the Mac way!

Comment: Did you take a look at the sample code on my website? It has a simple structure set. Stick with the objc, it DOES take a while but I love it, otherwise I wouldn't have set up an agency specialising in it!

Comment: Cheers Simon, thanks again and congrats on what looks like a good agency. Keep up the good work!